# Indexing into N-D matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a matrix M (4*2) with values:

```
[1 0;
 0 0;
 1 1;
 0 1]
```

And an array `X = [0.3 0.4 0.5 0.2];`

All column entries of `M` are binary (0/1). What I want is a corresponding row value mapped into a ND-array of `[2,2]` called `Z`. Each dimension here indicates 0/1, by having it in the first row or second row. `X(1)` needs to go to `Z(2,1)` and `X(2)` needs to go to `Z(1,1)` and so on..

Z will look like this:

```
Z = 
[0.4 0.2;
 0.3 0.5];
```

Currently I am looping over this, but it is really expensive to do so. Please note that this is a minimal example - I need to do this for a 128*7 matrix into a 7D array.

Any suggestions on how to speed up this process?

Comment: Please provide an example output of what you're expecting given the above sample inputs.  It's a bit difficult to understand what it is you want.

Comment: Is this a typo: `X(1) needs to go to Z(2,2)`? If I'm reading your description correctly you want `Z(2,1) = X(1)`.

Comment: @beaker, yes you are correct. Fixed the typo, thanks!
@ rayryeng Point well taken. I have added what Z should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [accumarray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) (not sure if it's faster):

```
>> Z = accumarray(M + 1, X, [2 2])

Z =

    0.4000    0.2000
    0.2000    0.5000
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, but does not seem optimal in terms of timing!

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
D=[1 0;0 0;1 1;0 1]; X = [0.3 0.4 0.5 0.2];

Z(sub2ind([2 2], D(:, 1) + 1, D(:, 2) + 1)) = X;
Z = reshape(Z, 2, 2);
```

*EDIT*

Most of the overhead of sub2ind is, unfortunately, error checking. If you are comfortable that all your D values are in range, you can effectively inline the sub2ind operation. Here's an example:

```
ndx = M(:, 1) + 1;
ndx = ndx + M(:, 2) * 2;
Z2=[];
Z2(ndx) = X;
Z2 = reshape(Z2, 2, 2);
```

Using this code and the timing test in @johnnyfuego's answer, I get

```
Elapsed time is 0.154196 seconds.    <--- johnny's
Elapsed time is 0.288680 seconds.    <--- mine
Elapsed time is 0.143874 seconds.
```

So, better, but still not beating the other two. However, note that there is a break-even point here. If I change the setup code in the time test to

```
M = randi(2, 1000, 2) - 1;
X = rand(1, 1000);
```

That is, I bump the number of values to write up from 4 to 1000, then the time trial results in

```
Elapsed time is 3.650833 seconds.     <--- johnny's
Elapsed time is 0.607361 seconds.     <--- mine
Elapsed time is 0.872595 seconds.
```

*EDIT #2*

Here's how you would unroll a multidimensional sub2ind:

```
siz = [2 2 2 2 2 2 2];
offsets = cumprod(siz);
ndx = M(:, 1) + 1;
ndx = ndx + M(:, 2) * offsets(1);
ndx = ndx + M(:, 3) * offsets(2);
ndx = ndx + M(:, 4) * offsets(3);
ndx = ndx + M(:, 5) * offsets(4);
ndx = ndx + M(:, 6) * offsets(5);
ndx = ndx + M(:, 7) * offsets(6);
Z2=[];
Z2(ndx) = X;
Z2 = reshape(Z2, [siz]);
```

Using that with your updated time test I get:

```
Elapsed time is 43.754363 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.045980 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.689487 seconds.
```

So, still better than looping, but it looks like in this multidimensional case accumarray (Rafael's answer) wins. I'd consider awarding him the "accepted answer" points.

Comment: This is the answer I was thinking of. Either this or `sparse`.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work, but is rather slow. Please see my post for a comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the update!

I don't really know how to extend your example to an N-D array, but if I time my implementations again with the actual data that I am using, you already win. Please see my post for an update.

Comment: Thanks! I have indeed given Rafael the accepted answer points. Thanks for the back and forth on this, very educative.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @rafael-monteiro & @SCFRench.

My original procedure was faster. I have pasted a benchmarking script below.

```
M=[1 0; 0 0; 1 1; 0 1];

X = [0.3 0.4 0.5 0.2];

nrep=50000;


%% My own code
tic
for A=1:nrep;
    MN=M+1; % I know I can do this outside of the loop, but comparison with this seems more fair.
    Z=zeros(size(X,2)/2,size(X,2)/2); % without pre-allocation it is twice as fast, I guess finding the size and the computation does not help here!
    for I=1:4
        Z1(MN(I,1),MN(I,2))=X(I);
    end
end
toc

%% SCFrench code
tic
for A=1:nrep;
    Z2(sub2ind([2 2], M(:, 1) + 1, M(:, 2) + 1)) = X;
    Z2 = reshape(Z2, 2, 2);
end
toc

%% Rafael code
tic
for A=1:nrep;
    Z3 = accumarray(M + 1, X, [2 2]);
end
toc

Elapsed time is 0.115488 seconds. % mine
Elapsed time is 1.082505 seconds. % SCFrench
Elapsed time is 0.282693 seconds. % rafael
```

EDIT:

Using larger data, the first implementation seems far slower.

```
alts=7;
M = dec2bin(0:2^alts-1)-'0';  
X = rand(size(M,1),1);
nrep=50000;

tic
for A=1:nrep;
    MN=M+1;
    for I=1:128
        Z1(MN(I,1),MN(I,2),MN(I,3),MN(I,4),MN(I,5),MN(I,6),MN(I,7))=X(I);
    end
end
toc

tic
for A=1:nrep;
    Z2(sub2ind([2 2 2 2 2 2 2], M(:, 1) + 1, M(:, 2) + 1, M(:, 3) + 1, M(:, 4)     + 1, M(:, 5) + 1, M(:, 6) + 1, M(:, 7) + 1)) = X;
    Z2 = reshape(Z2, [2 2 2 2 2 2 2]);
end
toc

tic
for A=1:nrep;
    Z3 = accumarray(M + 1, X, [2 2 2 2 2 2 2]);
end
toc

Elapsed time is 33.390247 seconds. % Mine
Elapsed time is 4.280668 seconds.  % SCFrench
Elapsed time is 0.629584 seconds.  % Rafael
```